# Flutter : Firebase PhoneAuthentication Problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, navigation

I have just developed an app which requires phone authentication. Inside login screen I can able to achieve to login via phone. But my concern is : for the first time when I enter phone number and enter verification number it comes back to login which in reality expected to navigate to homescreen. For the second try system is able to work and navigate to home screen as expected. Here is my code block. I am wondering which part of the code I make mistake since login info pop back again and system is able to navigate to home screen after second try:

My code block :

```
        class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
           String phoneNo, smssent, verificationId;

           get verifiedSuccess => null;

        Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
         final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {
         this.verificationId = verId;
            };
         final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResent]) {
         this.verificationId = verId;
         smsCodeDialoge(context).then((value) {
         print("Doğrulama Kodu Gönderildi");
            });
              };
         final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (AuthCredential auth) {};
         final PhoneVerificationFailed verifyFailed = (AuthException e) {
         print('${e.message}');
              };
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNo,
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
          verificationFailed: verifyFailed,
          codeSent: smsCodeSent,
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
              );
                }

            Future<bool> smsCodeDialoge(BuildContext context) {
            return showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return new AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Doğrulama Kodunu Giriniz'),
                content: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                this.smssent = value;
                   },
                     ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                     FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                         FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                          if (user != null) {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                             );
                           } else {
                           Navigator.of(context).pop();
                               signIn(smssent);
                            }
                              });
                                  },
                               child: Text(
                                 'Doğrulama Yap',
                                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                                     ),
                                        ),
                                           ],
                                              );
                                                 });
                                                     }

                     Future<void> signIn(String smsCode) async {
                     final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                     verificationId: verificationId,
                     smsCode: smsCode,
                        );

                                                                                         
          await     FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user)               
                  { 
                  Navigator.push(
                   context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                     builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                         ),
                              );
                              }).catchError((e) {
                            print(e);
                                 });
                                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (user != null) {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                             );
```

Here you are calling pop, which will take you to the previous screen if the user is not null, and after that, you are pushing the HomeScreen into the stack. Try not poping and just pushing, by the way, are you using routes and streamprovider in your code?